# Comparison of IPTW Methods and the Role of Multivariable Regression in Small Sample Sizes

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, propensity-scores

I recently conducted an observational study with a relatively small sample size, comprising three groups (A: 30 patients, B: 500 patients, C: 30 patients) with varying event rates (5-10%). To estimate treatment effects, I employed Inverse Probability of Treatment Weighting (IPTW) using several methods, including glm, CBPS, nCBPS, BART, SL, energy, among others, and computed both Average Treatment Effect (ATE) and Average Treatment Effect on the Treated (ATT).

After extensive analysis, I chose the Energy method based on standardized mean differences (SMDs) for 14 covariates, as it demonstrated the best balance between the treatment groups. The outcome of interest in my study is death, and I used a Cox Proportional Hazard model for the outcome analysis. This model included 13 covariates, most of which overlapped with the covariates used in the IPTW model. Additionally, I encountered convergence issues in the outcome model due to the low event rate, which made it impossible to include certain variables.

I have two primary questions that I would appreciate insights on:

1. Multivariable Regression with IPTW in Small Sample Sizes:

Is multivariable regression after implementing IPTW superior to performing multivariable regression alone in studies with small sample sizes? While there is limited literature addressing this issue, I am concerned about potential distortions in the IPTW model. Therefore, I am contemplating using multivariable Cox regression without IPTW as the primary analysis. I would appreciate guidance and discussions on the pros and cons of this approach.

2. Data-Driven Selection of IPTW Method:

Can data-driven selection of the IPTW method be justified? I selected the Energy method based on its better SMD results for covariates (SMD over 0.2: 2). However, I've encountered questions and skepticism from clinicians and biostatisticians regarding the validity of this approach. I'm curious if there are well-documented cases or papers that advocate for specific IPTW methods under certain circumstances. Insights and recommendations on this aspect would be invaluable.

Lastly, I'd like to express my gratitude to Noah for developing the "weightit" R package, which has been instrumental in my study.

Thank you for any input or guidance you can provide.

Best regards,

Comment: Why didn't you just use treatment as a covariate in your analysis?

Comment: Dear geek45,

Thank you for your input and question. I appreciate your suggestion, and I'd like to clarify that I did include the treatment variable as a covariate in my outcome model. This is because my primary interest lies in estimating the hazard ratio associated with the treatment effect.

To provide context, my study involves a comparative effectiveness analysis using real-world data (RWD). I aim to provide a robust and well-controlled analysis of the treatment's effect on the outcome while considering confounding factors.

Thank you once again for your engagement.

Comment: Okay. I thought you included every covariate which you already used for balancing in your PS model.

Comment: IMO you indeed have to compare the crude, 'unweighted' estimates as well as the IPTW.